# Some value from Postman test undefined

Tags: automated-testing, api, postman, debugging

I need to create tests in `Postman` for running key values for the `AI Conversation` app.
I have created tests, where I have used the logic below, where I can see all of the values after a test run except `actual_cpid`
For all values, I have used https://jsonpathfinder.com/

`Postman` doesn't show this value in the result. Could you please help me figure out what I have missed?

Here is my code for `Postman`:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let utterance = jsonData.utterance;
let actual_intent = jsonData.intent.name;
let expected_intent = pm.variables.get("intent");
let actual_grammar = jsonData.grammars.speech_grammar;
let actual_cpid = jsonData.dialog_metadata.outgoing_data.data.CALLPURPOSE_ID;
let actual_dnis = jsonData.dialog_metadata.destination_uri;

tests[" ," + utterance + ", " + 
            expected_intent + ", " + 
            actual_intent + ", " + 
            actual_grammar + ", " +
            actual_cpid + ", " +
            actual_dnis + ", " +
            pm.environment.get("dialog_id")
            ] = true;
```

Comment: Could you please post your response body?

Comment: Response body was not logged